# how to run phpcode when html button is clicked

Tags: php, html

I have a registration form and a button when onclick should upload the files in server before the form is submitted. How could i run the PHPscript whenever the button is clicked to upload the files

Comment: you cant do that, work on client-side to send a request to PHP using AJAX.. instead of doing that from scratch try searching for ajax file uploaders

Comment: It is a good idea to learn [how php works](http://devzone.zend.com/6/php-101-php-for-the-absolute-beginner/)

Comment: can i upload the files using Ajax

Answer (score 1):

This should answer your question:

[Ajax File Upload with PHP](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/)

The HTML code:

```
<form id="file_upload_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
<input name="file" id="file" size="27" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Upload" /><br />
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
</form>
```

The Javascript:

```
function init() {
    document.getElementById('file_upload_form').onsubmit=function() {
        document.getElementById('file_upload_form').target = 'upload_target'; //'upload_target' is the name of the iframe
    }
}
window.onload=init;
```

The `upload.php` PHP code (Some code excluded for brevity):

```
<?php
...
if($_FILES['image']['name']) {
    list($file,$error) = upload('image','uploads/','jpeg,gif,png');
    if($error) print $error;
}
...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better you go on with Ajax rather trying to scratch your head for something that is impossible without Ajax. because you want to post a partial functionality and then the actual submit. you can start learning [Basic Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) or you can directly use any [Ajax Framework](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

[Here are Some](http://www.queness.com/post/11434/7-javascript-ajax-file-upload-plugins) already build Ajax uploaders, you can check and use them with your application